# Loop through an optional object in Swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, option-type

I have this code

```
let dic = snapshot.value as! [String:[String:Any]]
Array(dic.values).forEach {
    print($0["fcmToken"])
}
```

It produce these 3

```
Optional(c1DdtdDF1Rs:APA91bGJBUD65nidQiFDO90AVNgq0wiMjUaZmZXVJ8c_tYmFe5dkmgweOdO10jzPRlMVZF_qNyWMMsu7EhA5IMVo3jLWvBThDteR7WWUPqau-ZFAHKQPHgI5Vb48vA-_4nwkZCKrOVoT)
Optional(c1DdtdDF1Rs:APA91bGJBUD65nidQiFDO90AVNgq0wiMjUaZmZXVJ8c_tYmFe5dkmgweOdO10jzPRlMVZF_qNyWMMsu7EhA5IMVo3jLWvBThDteR7WWUPqau-ZFAHKQPHgI5Vb48vA-_4nwkZCKrOVoT)
Optional(c1DdtdDF1Rs:APA91bGJBUD65nidQiFDO90AVNgq0wiMjUaZmZXVJ8c_tYmFe5dkmgweOdO10jzPRlMVZF_qNyWMMsu7EhA5IMVo3jLWvBThDteR7WWUPqau-ZFAHKQPHgI5Vb48vA-_4nwkZCKrOVoT)
```

I want to loop through them and add a simple if-check.

I tried

```
let dic = snapshot.value as! [String:[String:Any]]
Array(dic.values).forEach {
    print($0["fcmToken"])

    if($0["fcmToken"] != fcmToken) {
        print("token is not match detected")
    }

}
```

I kept getting

> Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any?' and 'String?'

How would one go about debugging this further?

Comment: Well, the question is why do you even use an ugly type like `[String: [String: Any]]`? Why don't use use a structs, where `fcmToken` would be actually defined as a `String` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
let dic = snapshot.value as! [String:[String:Any]]
Array(dic.values).forEach {
    print($0["fcmToken"])
    if($0["fcmToken"] != fcmToken) {
        print("token is not match detected")
    }
}
```

But it’s giving you a compile error. 
Assuming that this line is working:

```
let dic = snapshot.value as! [String:[String:Any]]
```

I'd write the rest like this:

```
for v in dic.values {
    if let token = v["fcmtoken"] as? String, token != fcmtoken {
        print("token \(token) is not match detected")
    }
}
```

The effect is the same and there’s no error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
let dic = snapshot.value as! [String:[String:Any]]
let tokens = Array(dic.values).map { $0["fcmToken"] as! String }
let exists = tokens.contains(fcmToken)
```

Your problem as `$0["fcmToken"]` is of type `Any?` that can't compared with type `String?` ( `fcmToken` )

---

```
let dic = snapshot.value as! [String:[String:Any]]
Array(dic.values).forEach {
    print($0["fcmToken"])

    if let token =  $0["fcmToken"] as? String , token != fcmToken {
        print("token is not match detected")
    }

   // or

    if  ($0["fcmToken"] as? String) != fcmToken {
        print("token is not match detected")
    }

}
```

You can savely use

```
guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: [String:Any]] else {
  return
}
```

but it won't function when the value is nil

Comment: How do I loop through my token and run an if-check () ?

Comment: Let me see, I will check now.

Comment: You have a typo in your answer `toekn` Other than that, I'm trying now.

Comment: or simplified just `if ($0["fcmToken"] as? String) != fcmToken {`, of course, this is still not the optimal solution. The optimal solution is to convert that ugly nested untyped dictionary to structures first.

Comment: @Sulthan Quickly tried your line when see your comment, I got this : https://i.imgur.com/4ItHUym.png

Comment: @kyo Obviously, there was a typo single quote vs double quote.

Comment: Ok, I will try that again 

Comment: @Sulthan seem compiled fine, when run crash at this line : https://i.imgur.com/xMhNuXO.png

Comment: @Sh_Khan You exact code in the answer now also produce this issue : https://i.imgur.com/VnW0dLa.png

Comment: check your firebase users table may be overwritten

Comment: It has nothing there ... null. How do we prevent that ?

Comment: @kyo look to save way in answer ,  it worked before that means you may have some problems

Comment: if you need to know whether the token exists or not in the users table , the first block in my answer is the shortest way